# Windows preview builds have broken the Transactional File System?

Tags: windows, filesystems, transactional

The new Windows preview builds (18252+) are manifesting a breaking change in the behavior of the NTFS TxF (transactional file system -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/transactional-ntfs-portal) with 100% reproducibility. Steps are:

1) Open a TxF transaction.
2) Create a new temp directory in some path within the transaction.
3) Open zip file within the transaction.
4) Extract all the files in the zip files into the directory within the transaction.
5) Create another new destination directory within the transaction.
6) Move the files from the temp directory to the destination directory within the transaction.

Step 6 results in a "The system cannot find the path specified" error, as if step 5 had failed or wasn't recorded by the transaction.

Is this a known problem?